# Error consume JSON with JS

Tags: javascript, java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I have a JS problem with Java using Spring. I made some WebServices and PHP is running smoothly, but I need to access them using JS. I've tried everything, still is not calling my service

Below my code in Java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map")
public class MapRest {

@Autowired
private MapService mapService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchCarByUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<RetornoMapa> searchCarByUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    RetornMap retornMap = new RetornMap();
    try {
        List<Car> list = mapService.search(user);
        retornMap.setListCar(list);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.logError("Error", e);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(retornMap, HttpStatus.OK);
}

}
```

Now my code in JS

```
function testeJson() {
var user = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jonh'
};
var json = JSON.stringify(user);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/orion/webservice/map/searchCarByUser",
    traditional: true,
    data: json,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }, error: function (jqXHR, status) {
        // error handler
        console.log(jqXHR);
        alert('fail' + status.code);
    }
});
}
```

When I call the JS function always returns the status equal to 404.

When I use the Advanced REST Client of Chrome, usually calls the service listed above.

I would like to know from you where I am going wrong?
What should be done?

Comment: Are you sure that the url you put is correct?

Comment: are you sending to different port than page is on? If so need to implement CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first slash from the method `@Path` annotation:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/map")
public class MapRest {

@Autowired
private MapService mapService;

@RequestMapping(value = "searchCarByUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<RetornoMapa> searchCarByUser(@RequestBody User user) {
//...
```

The `@Path` of each method follows the same rules as, say, the path from an `href="..."` attribute: if it starts with a slash, it's an absolute path, else it's a relative path (in this case relative to the base class' `@Path`).

Having that in mind, your currrent JS code should work if you call `http://localhost:8080/orion/webservice/searchCarByUser` instead (without the `/map` part), you can test it if you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mapping at the controller and keep it at method as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/map/searchCarByUser", .....
```

Because, the path in @RequestMapping on the method is relative to the path on the class annotation.

Comment: Thank you for your help!